# C++ smart pointer const correctness

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr

I have a few containers in a class, for example, vector or map which contain
shared_ptr's to objects living on the heap.

For example

```
template <typename T>
class MyExample
{
public:

private:
    vector<shared_ptr<T> > vec_;
    map<shared_ptr<T>, int> map_;
};
```

I want to have a public interface of this class that sometimes returns shared_ptrs to const objects (via `shared_ptr<const T>`) and sometimes `shared_ptr<T>` where I allow the caller to mutate the objects.

I want logical const correctness, so if I mark a method as const, it cannot change the objects on the heap.

Questions:

1) I am confused by the interchangeability of `shared_ptr<const T>` and `shared_ptr<T>`. When someone passes a `shared_ptr<const T>` into the class, do I:

- Store it as a `shared_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<const T>` inside the container?
- OR
- Do I change the map, vector types (e.g. insert_element(`shared_ptr<const T>` obj)?

2) Is it better to instantiate classes as follows: `MyExample<const int>`? That seems unduly restrictive, because I can never return a `shared_ptr<int>`?

Answer (score 40):

`shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<const T>` are **not** interchangable. It goes one way - `shared_ptr<T>` is convertable to `shared_ptr<const T>` but not the reverse.

Observe:

```
// f.cpp

#include <memory>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    shared_ptr<int> pint(new int(4)); // normal shared_ptr
    shared_ptr<const int> pcint = pint; // shared_ptr<const T> from shared_ptr<T>
    shared_ptr<int> pint2 = pcint; // error! comment out to compile
}
```

compile via

> cl /EHsc f.cpp

You can also overload a function based on a constness. You can combine to do these two facts to do what you want.

As for your second question, `MyExample<int>` probably makes more sense than `MyExample<const int>`.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest the following methotology:

```
template <typename T>
class MyExample
{
  private:
    vector<shared_ptr<T> > data;

  public:
    shared_ptr<const T> get(int idx) const
    {
      return data[idx];
    }
    shared_ptr<T> get(int idx)
    {
      return data[idx];
    }
    void add(shared_ptr<T> value)
    {
      data.push_back(value);
    }
};
```

This ensures const-correctness. Like you see the add() method does not use <const T> but <T> because you intend the class to store Ts not const Ts. But when accessing it const, you return <const T> which is no problem since shared_ptr<T> can easily be converted to shared_ptr<const T>. And sice both get() methods return copies of the shared_ptr's in your internal storage the caller can not accidentally change the object your internal pointers point to. This is all comparable to the non-smart pointer variant:

```
template <typename T>
class MyExamplePtr
{
  private:
    vector<T *> data;

  public:
    const T *get(int idx) const
    {
      return data[idx];
    }
    T *get(int idx)
    {
      return data[idx];
    }
    void add(T *value)
    {
      data.push_back(value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Should it not be that `shared_ptr<T>` can easily be converted
to shared_ptr<const T>` and not the other way around?

Comment: When returning just a simple member then overloading seem like not a big deal. But what if you return a `shared_ptr` from a `vector` - where you have to calculate which one is the correct one. How do you avoid code duplication?

Answer (score 6):

If someone passes you a `shared_ptr<const T>` you should never be able to modify `T`.  It is, of course, technically possible to cast the `const T` to just a `T`, but that breaks the intent of making the `T` `const`.  So if you want people to be able to add objects to your class, they should be giving you `shared_ptr<T>` and no `shared_ptr<const T>`.  When you return things from your class you do not want modified, that is when you use `shared_ptr<const T>`.

`shared_ptr<T>` can be automatically converted (without an explicit cast) to a `shared_ptr<const T>` but not the other way around.  It may help you (and you should do it anyway) to make liberal use of `const` methods.  When you define a class method `const`, the compiler will not let you modify any of your data members or return anything except a `const T`.  So using these methods will help you make sure you didn't forget something, and will help users of your class understand what the intent of the method is.  (Example: `virtual shared_ptr<const T> myGetSharedPtr(int index) const;`)

You are correct on your second statement, you probably do not want to instantiate your class as `<const T>`, since you will never be able to modify any of your `T`s.

Answer (score 3):

one thing to realize is that:

`tr1::shared_ptr<const T>` is mimicking the functionality of `T const *` namely what it points to is const, but the pointer itself isn't.

So you can assign a new value to your shared pointer, but I would expect that you wouldn't be able to use the dereferenced `shared_ptr` as an l-value.

Comment: "l-value." An l-value need not be assignable!

Answer (score 0):

## Prologue

The `const` qualifier changes the behaviour of `std::shared_ptr`, just like it affects the legacy C pointers.

Smart pointers should be managed and stored using the right qualifiers at all times to prevent, enforce and help programmers to treat them rightfully.

## Answers

> 1. When someone passes a `shared_ptr<const T>` into the class, do I store it as a `shared_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<const T>` inside the vector and map or do I change the map, vector types?

If your API accepts a `shared_ptr<const T>`, the unspoken contract between the caller and yourself is that you are NOT allowed to change the `T` object pointed by the pointer, thus, you have to keep it as such in your internal containers, e.g. `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const T>>`.

Moreover, your module should NEVER be able/allowed to return `std::shared_ptr<T>`, even though one can programatically achieve this (See my answer to the second question to see how).

> 2. Is it better to instantiate classes as follows: `MyExample<const int>`? That seems unduly restrictive, because I can never return a `shared_ptr<int>`?

It depends:

- If you designed your module so that objects passed to it should not change again in the future, use `const T` as the underlying type.
- If you your module should be able to return non-const `T` pointers, you should use `T` as your underlying type and probably have two different getters, one that returns mutable objects (`std::shared_ptr<T>`) and another that returns non-mutable objects (`std::shared_ptr<const T>`).

And, even though I hope we just agreed you **should not** return `std::shared_ptr<T>` if you have a `const T` or `std::shared_ptr<const T>`, you **can**:

```
const T a = 10;
auto a_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(const_cast<T>(a));

auto b_const_ptr = std::make_shared<const T>();
auto b_ptr = std::const_pointer_cast<T>(b_const_ptr);
```

## Full blown example

Consider the following example that covers all the possible permutations of `const` with `std::shared_ptr`:

```
struct Obj
{
  int val = 0;
};

int main()
{
    // Type #1:
    // ------------
    // Create non-const pointer to non-const object
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> ptr1 = std::make_shared<Obj>();
    // We can change the underlying object inside the pointer
    ptr1->val = 1;
    // We can change the pointer object
    ptr1 = nullptr;

    // Type #2:
    // ------------
    // Create non-const pointer to const object
    std::shared_ptr<const Obj> ptr2 = std::make_shared<const Obj>();
    // We cannot change the underlying object inside the pointer
    ptr2->val = 3; // <-- ERROR
    // We can change the pointer object
    ptr2 = nullptr;

    // Type #3:
    // ------------
    // Create const pointer to non-const object
    const std::shared_ptr<Obj> ptr3 = std::make_shared<Obj>();
    // We can change the underlying object inside the pointer
    ptr3->val = 3;
    // We can change the pointer object
    ptr3 = nullptr; // <-- ERROR

    // Type #4:
    // ------------
    // Create const pointer to non-const object
    const std::shared_ptr<const Obj> ptr4 = std::make_shared<const Obj>();
    // We can change the underlying object inside the pointer
    ptr4->val = 4; // <-- ERROR
    // We can change the pointer object
    ptr4 = nullptr; // <-- ERROR

    // Assignments:
    // ------------
    // Conversions between objects
    // We cannot assign to ptr3 and ptr4, because they are const
    ptr1 = ptr4 // <-- ERROR, cannot convert 'const Obj' to 'Obj'
    ptr1 = ptr3;
    ptr1 = ptr2 // <-- ERROR, cannot convert 'const Obj' to 'Obj'

    ptr2 = ptr4;
    ptr2 = ptr3;
    ptr2 = ptr1;
}
```

**Note**: The following is true when managing all types of smart pointers. The assignment of pointers might differ (e.g. when handling `unique_ptr`), but the concept it the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, there exists [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const/) that addresses exactly this issue.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <experimental/propagate_const>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class MyExample
{
public:
   
    template <typename U>
    using pointer_t = std::experimental::propagate_const<std::shared_ptr<U>>;


    std::vector<pointer_t<T> > vec_;
    std::map<pointer_t<T>, int> map_;
};

int main() {

    auto x = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    MyExample<int> e;
    e.vec_.push_back(x);

    // non-const getter will propagate mutability through the pointer
    {
        auto& test = e.vec_[0];
        static_assert(std::is_same<int&, decltype(*test)>::value);
    }

    // const-getter will propagate const through the pointer
    {
        MyExample<int> const& ec = e;
        auto& test = ec.vec_[0];
        static_assert(std::is_same<int const&, decltype(*test)>::value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ej3hPsqMo

If you are uncomfortable using the experimental namespace, or if you are using MSVC (as far as i know MSVC hasn't implemented this feature yet), you can implement your own version of `propagate_const`. A protoype could look like this:

```cpp
template <typename Ptr>
class propagate_const
{
public:
    using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*Ptr{})>::type;

    template <
        typename T,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T, Ptr>::value>
    >
    constexpr propagate_const(T&& p) : ptr{std::forward<T>(p)} {}

    constexpr value_type& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    constexpr value_type const& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    constexpr value_type& operator->() { return *ptr; }
    constexpr value_type const& operator->() const { return *ptr; }

private:
    Ptr ptr;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rbKcr3M66